# Hola. Estoy aprendiendo ensamblador me gustaria saber como podria lograr que el resultado salga invertido. (Es la cadena de numero figgonachi)

Tags: ensamblador, assembly

```
mov cx, 20
mov si, -1
mov di, 1
ciclo:
    mov ax, si
    add ax, di
    
    mov si, di
    mov di, ax
    
    mov dx,"$$"
    push dx
apila:    
    mov bx,10  
    mov dx,0
    div bx
    push dx
    cmp ax, 0
    jg apila  
depila:
    pop dx
    cmp dx,"$$"
    je findepila
    add dx, 30h
    mov ah,2
    int 21h
    jmp depila
findepila:
    mov dl,32
    mov ah,2
    int 21h
    loop ciclo
```

Solo me falta saber como hacer la inversion de la cadena. No tengo idea. El numero figgonachi deberia salir de la sig forma: 4181 2584 1597 987 610 377 233 144 89 55 34 21 13 8 5 3 2 1 1 0
Pero al reves. Es lo que quiero aplicar.

Comment: Los números son de _Fibonacci_, a no ser que se haya creado otro tipo de secuencia :)

Comment: Si! lo que tengo que hacer es invertir los numeros de Fibonacci. Tiene su limite.